# data-traget attribute undefined in django templates and Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, django, django-templates

Am trying to access the data-target value , it was working but then it stopped unexpectedly, below is my html "

```
<div class="loan-pending" id='loan-pending-{{loan.loan_id}}' data-target="loan-pending-data-{{loan.id}}" data-query-loan-id="loan={{loan.id}}">
            {% trans 'Loan Applications' %}: {{loan.loan_id}}
          </div>
```

Then, this is the jquery :

```
const loanPendingData = $(`#loan-pending-data-${loanID}`);
```

I also tried , the following :

```
const loanPendingData = $(this).data('target');
```

Full js script :

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  (function ($) {
    "use strict";

    $(document).ready(function () {
     

      checkQueryParamsForPendingLoans();
     
      function checkQueryParamsForPendingLoans() {
         const loanPendingData = $(`#loan-pending-data-${loanID}`);
       }
     }
})(django.jQuery);
```

but no luck , what causes this in django and jquery ?

Comment: What does `loanID` looks like? is it the same value as `loan.loan_id`? Also It would be helpt to see what events runs those codes of jquery that you are showing us

Comment: `loanID` is the same as `loan.id` , and it's primary key, e.g `239`

Comment: What do you mean by events ?

Comment: Added more code @CarstenLøvboAndersen, kindly have a look

Comment: Did you tried using class ? Also did you tried to print `${loanID}` because i am not seeing where you have assign value to that .

Comment: Actually it finally worked, I had an error in the id